# Converting VB.NET event to C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am looking at the old VB.net code

```
Public Event TagDetected(ByVal t As Tag)
...
RaiseEvent TagDetected(t)
```

that I am trying to convert to C#. My attempt:

```
public event EventHandler<Tag> TagDetected;
...
TagDetected(this, t.Clone());
```

doesn't work and gives me an error:

> Error  1   The type 'XYZ.VKM.Common.Tag' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEventArgs' in the generic type or method 'System.EventHandler'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'XYZ.VKM.Common.Tag' to 'System.EventArgs'.

Comment: How is the event triggered?

Comment: @Ckrempp Do you mean how the even was raised or you mean what code is ran when the event is raised ?

I have no idea what code will be ran when the event is raised (and in fact was explicitly asked not to modify it). I.e it will be handled somewhere behind the scene.

Comment: I mean what action raises the event, like a mouse click, or key press.

Comment: It is raised within a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [EventHandler{TEventArgs} delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx) is for a function that takes a generic type which derived from the [EventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs.aspx) class. In your example, the `Tag` class doesn't derive from `EventArgs` which is why you're getting an error.

The `event` keyword doesn't have to be used with either the `EventHandler` or `EventHandler{TEventArgs}` delegates, but actually any delegate. In this particular case you can better translate the code as follows:

```
public event Action<Tag> TagDetected;
...
TagDetected(t.Clone());
```

Comment: Where is everyone getting the generic aspect from? There is no generic flavor in the original VB code at all.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas I only brought it up because of his translation. I believe VB is automatically creating an action delegate in the event decoration in the VB code, which most easily translates to a generic `action` in C#.

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant to write:

```
public event EventHandler<TagEventArgs> TagDetected;
```

where TagEventArgs is your own child class of EventArgs, exposing a DetectedTag property.  This makes sure that the event handler pattern is tightly observed (i.e. you can always refer to the EventArgs as EventArgs in any handler, not having to know that they're just an int, or in your case, just a tag).

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 forms of an event declaration in VB - one uses an explicit delegate type and the other uses an implicit delegate type - you used the implicit delegate approach. C# only has the explicit delegate type approach.
The equivalent C# code is:

```
public delegate void TagDetectedEventHandler(Tag t);
public event TagDetectedEventHandler TagDetected;
```